# "Supposing" vs "what if"

Tags: sentence-meaning

M. Swan said that **supposing**, **supposed** and **what if** could be used to untroduce suggestions. He provide and example:

> 'Daddy can I watch TV?' Supposing you did your homework first?

As far as I understand *supposing you did your homework first?* asks whether the homework have been done, right?

Will the sense be changed if we substitute **supposing** to **what if**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Supposing' or 'I suppose that' means I think or believe it is true. I don't think supposing can replace "what if",  which means what would happen if a particular thing does not happen such as what if I fail the driving test?, what if I don't do what you say?, etc. So there is a difference in meaning between these two phrases.

Answer (score 1):

Daddy can I watch TV?

- No, you have homework to do.

Supposing I did my homework first?

- No, you also have some other chores to do.

What if I finished those chores as well?

- OK. Then you can watch TV.

Comment: Do you mean daddy propose to do the homework first, right?

Comment: Child asks if he would be allowed to watch TV if he finishes the homework beforehand.  Supposing = what if.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing 
It is present participle of suppose.
It means to think, to behave, to assume, to suppose etc,.
Supposed
It is past participle of suppose.

Comment: It seems like OP was asking about the meaning in this particular case, and also the meaning of their alternative. Could you [edit] your post to address that?